# throw exception from one method to another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am trying to throw exception from one method to another by that if any error occures then the main method will print it in message box. I have already done in c# but trying to write same in vb.net  but always giving error when i throw it to another method.Thanks in advance for help.

```
  Public Async Function test() As Task(Of DataSet)

    Try

        Dim ds As New DataSet



        Dim a, b As Integer
        a = "a"
        b = 7
        Dim c = a / b


        Await Task.Run(Function() adapter.Fill(ds))


    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try


    Return ds

  End Function
```

[image]

Comment: First already done it in C# but you chose not to show us that code? Secondly, if you have C# code and want VB code then how is VB.NET-to-C# an appropriate tag?

Comment: If you had `Option Strict On` - as you always should - then that code would not even compile because assigning a `String` to an `Integer` variable is not valid. The equivalent C# code would similarly fail to compile.

Comment: Where is the code where you call `test()` and catch its exception?

Comment: @AlexB. i call this code on textbox changes event

Comment: @jmcilhinney Dear Sir/Mam i am aware with this error but i just want to throw this error to another method only . and sorry for that i did not share you my c# code.

Comment: The code shown appears to be working as designed.  What do you think it should be doing?

Comment: @Craig i think it should throw above exception to the another method

Comment: Hit F5 to continue execution, and I think you will find that it continues to propagate.  The message says "Exception Thrown", which suggests that it's stopping because you have selected to break when the exception is thrown in the debugging exception settings (and I think this is generally a good practice).

Comment: If you have Option Strict On , which you should, this won't even compile.

Comment: Won't an exception go up the call stack without a Try...Catch until it is handled or is this different in an Async method? Why would you need to Throw at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
        Try
            Dim result = test()
            Dim x = result.Result()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Async Function test() As Task(Of Integer)
        Try
            Dim c = 1

            Await Test2()

            Await Task.Delay(1000)
            Return 40

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function

    Async Function Test2() As Task(Of String)
        Try
            Throw New Exception("mannual")

            Await Task.Delay(1000)

            Return "hello world "
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
```

[image]

Hi Prashant Please Check Your Function Call, rectified Reference attached, please look it CheckInner Exception [image]